# Android Studio configuration still incorrect along with app stopping in emulator

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a TTS for a school project. When I click run it says configuration still incorrect. However, the emulator still comes up, but when I click on the app to run it says it has stopped. I am very new to Android Studio so sorry if this seems like a dumb question. Here is what I have:

```
        package com.example.james.texttospeech;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

    //TTS object
    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    //status check code
    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    //create the Activity
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get a reference to the button element listed in the XML layout
        Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
        //listen for clicks
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    //respond to button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //get the text entered
        EditText enteredText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter);
        String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);
    }

    //speak the user text
    private void speakWords(String speech) {

        //speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    //act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }
            else {
                //no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    //setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat I know it's not pretty:

```
03-05 00:15:46.389    2264-2264/com.example.james.texttospeech D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
03-05 00:15:46.390    2264-2264/com.example.james.texttospeech E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.james.texttospeech, PID: 2264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.james.texttospeech/com.example.james.texttospeech.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.james.texttospeech.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.james.texttospeech-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.james.texttospeech.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.james.texttospeech-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.james.texttospeech.MainActivity
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.james.texttospeech" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add your logcat?

Comment: Put a break point in `OnCreate` and debug line by line.

Comment: Updated to add the logcat. Now at times it is saying app not installed but I click again and it gives me the app stop.

Comment: would you please append `MainActivity.java` also?

Comment: And, note that your activity class should have `public`

Comment: check you Android Studio configurations are properly done.

Comment: However, some of the words I input whatever it is using to speak does not know how to pronounce it. Is there a way to fix that? Also how would I put a different voice in?

Comment: So I changed SpeakingAndroid to MainActivity and put a public in front. For some reason when I was originally doing it, it was telling me to make it private and wasn't flagging that it wasn't MainActivity.

Comment: Now as part of our project we want to put a button when pushed will say something every minute for lets say 10 minutes... Is there a way to do that with Android?